# Jquery Mobile Dynamic collapsible contents are not taking any style

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am trying to create the dynamic collapsible divs using jquery mobile but the generated div are not taking any styles.

Can anybody solve this issue. :)

```
        jQuery.get('../config/la/english.txt', function(data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //alert(data[i]);
                $('<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" id="'+data[i]+'"><h3>'+ data[i] +'</h3></div>').appendTo("div#main");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

$("Selector").find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();

Comment: I load a bunch of these collapsibles for a non-inset list in a separate div and this works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding

`$(data[i]).collapsible({refresh:true});`

in the for-loop, after appending the div to your `<div#main>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the collapsible()  method after you finish the Loop in which you are creating the div elements.

Use the container DIV (which contains all the collapsible div elements you created) to call the collapsible() like so :

$('#container').find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();